# Clean up Windows driver packages

Tags: windows, drivers

We have a folder with a lot of drivers that is necessary for different computers in our network (Some HP driver, some Dell etc.).

Each computer in the domain is configured to scan a shared folder on the server for drivers to be installed and this "Scanning preconfigured driver folder" (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753716.aspx) takes very long time and I suspect it could be related to that the folder of drivers is over 4GB large with more than 7000 files in it.

I would like to know if there is a way to **clean up** these drivers folders, **leaving only** the required driver files: **inf,sys,cat,(dll)**?

The files could be anything from read me files and documentation (that I could manually remove of course) and other files that are not required for the driver to be properly installed, that I would like to be removed so the scanning process can be speeded up somehow

Comment: I don't know why I was downvoted, but I'm looking for either a tool to do this automatically, or how it could be achived manually, or better useful links to documentation that could be used to write a software to automate it.

Comment: I do not know why either, but i can tell you after reading it I still know little about your particular situation. If there are many computers sharing a driver repository? how they share that?  Which "driver folders" your referring to?  As to the 4G , my really clean and very careful win 7 which i dont play driver install games with much is ~2.5g and 5k files. Plus the original driver items and downloads  are stored in a space taking up  8G the bloody OS packs in 70K+ files.  When you ask about required, you could tell about any of the junk your referring to ?  Read_Me's? Licence files? Temps?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment! After reading my post I realized that it was unclerar what I meant. I hope the rewrite makes it more clear.
Yes I mean files like Readmes, licens files and tools and utilities that is not necessary for the driver to work properly.